# C# Mono Socket/Networking Library

Tags: gratis, library, c#, networking

I am looking for Mono.C# Networking Library for game purposes.

Here are features that I need to have in it:

- Free
- Async TCP and UDP (non blocking)
- Multi Threaded connections
- Event Driven
- Class serializing/deserializing (not neccesarry if it sends strings)
- Simple
- Platforms: Windows/Linux/Mac

I've tested:

- https://netsockets.codeplex.com/ **-** This one is great, but it lacks UDP (current choice)
- http://www.networkcomms.net/ **-** Free GPL version does not have necessary documentation and I had huge problems when building it. Also newest version is commercial.

Comment: what's wrong with the System.Net namespace?

Comment: It needs to be kept simple. If I'd use System.Net it would be equal to writting my own networking library, which is what I don't want to spend time on.

Comment: uh, what? Did you ever actually work with it? Serializing an object (including opening/closing a connection) is a whopping 5 lines of code.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4904/Asynchronous-Socket-Communications-Using-the-NET-F

Comment: Now compare it  to NetSockets which I am using right now. https://netsockets.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#netsockets/NetBox/Form1.cs

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on in the codeproject link, but this is how a connection is actually established: `var sender = new TcpClient(); sender.Connect(new IPEndPoint(targetAddress, port));  BinaryFormatter serializer = new BinaryFormatter();                            serializer.Serialize(sender.GetStream(), message);` where 'message' is a serializable object.

Comment: nvm. I just not going to use it. I am searching for a library.

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party, but: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Network/ does exactly what you want. [Source](https://github.com/Toemsel/Network)